# php artisan serve - how do I get mysql to run

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm new to all this artisan stuff. When I start my php server with

```
$ php artisan serve
```

How do I get the mysql server to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL server is independent of Laravel. The `artisan` command is just an interface to Laravel which runs PHP scripts in the background.

To start your MySQL server on Linux, you will have to run something like

```
sudo service mysql start
```

For Windows, you will get access to the server via WAMP or from the installed services.

Answer (score 0):

actually if you want to modify a little bit of laravel framework , you can do it like this:

open ServeCommand.php file on `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php`

then locate to `serverCommand()` function

add this command

```
echo shell_exec('sh your_terminal_command_to_start_mysql ');
```

everytime you run `php artisan serve` it will also execute your mysql service start command

Answer (score 0):

For Windows or Mac, you will need XAMPP installed to initiate MySQL. https://www.apachefriends.org